# Magento 1 print order from backend

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, backend, print

I need to print the order from the backend, the same as the customer is able to print the order from the account dashboard. now the catch is, the backend printed order needs to use the same design as the frontend one.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question with code which had tried ?

Comment: I have not tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in `print` button on the order page within the backend, as far as I'm aware it uses the same template in both admin and the front-end however I haven't researched this.

I know customising the invoice in Magento's in a pain in the arse quite frankly, we always recommend Fooman Pdf Customiser.

http://store.fooman.co.nz/magento-extension-pdf-customiser.html

Let me know if I haven't understood the problem properly.

Comment: actually we need to print the order html and not the pdf, as the html will be moore customization with css and both the frontend and backend order printouts needs to be same.